# $location.path() going to wrong url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html tag, and it displays fine when I do `Inspect Element`:

```
<tr style="cursor: pointer" ng-repeat="i in games" ng-click="go('/admin/{{i._id}}')">
```

When rendered looks like so:

```
<tr style="cursor: pointer" ng-repeat="i in games" ng-click="go('/admin/5550d868c5242fb3299a2604')" class="ng-scope">
```

for the javascript I then have this:

```
$scope.go = function(path){
    $location.path(path);
};
```

When the row is clicked, it should go here:

```
/admin/5550d868c5242fb3299a2604
```

but it goes here instead:

```
/admin/%7B%7Bi._id%7D%7D

Which evaluates to: {{i._id}}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: maybe ... ng-click="go('/admin/' + {{i._id}})

Comment: @ScottSelby What about it?

Comment: I would try it that way - I know that is not a proper fix , but see if taking the angular variable outside a string fixes it

Comment: With that it doesn't even attempt to load a page.

Comment: @ScottSelby That way does work without the `{{` and `}}`

Comment: First, console.log(path) to see exactly what you are getting in return when you use the go function.

Comment: I made an answer you can accept if you say that worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the parameter for [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) is itself an expression, no need to use curly braces there

```
ng-click="go('/admin/' + i._id)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I suggested in my comment  that I guess did work , and was taken in the other answer:

```
ng-click="go('/admin/' + i._id)"
```

the expression has to come out of the quotes